# How to resolve random invalid genesis block in ST 1.1.2?

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

I installed ST 1.1.2 with docker and I get inconsistent results. Sometimes the genesis block is generated just fine and I can submit new batches/blocks. On the other hand, sometimes the devmode processor doesn't process the genesis block because of "failed" consensus data.

I ran this on several AWS Ubuntu 16.04 instances, with the same random behavior. I also installed 1.1.2 natively with Ubuntu but got the same problem, only consistently.

```
sudo docker-compose -f sawtooth-default.yaml up
devmode_engine_rust: | Received message: BlockNew(Block(block_num: 0 ...*
devmode_engine_rust: | Checking consensus data: Block(block_num: 0 ...*
devmode_engine_rust: | Failed consensus check: Block(block_num: 0 ...*
devmode_engine_rust: | Failing block [86, ...*
sudo docker-compose -f sawtooth-defualt.yaml down
sudo docker-compose -f sawtooth-defualt.yaml up
```

I expect the genesis block to be validated everythime, instead of it happening around 50% of the time, even though I don't change anything in how I start the docker containers. What do I need to do in order for the devmode consensus process to always accept the genesis block at the first try?

Comment: Please add the 'validator' service statement from the docker-compose file to the question. It would be helpful to see the genesis block settings.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a timing issue. Is there a dependency on the validator container from the consensus container.  For example,

```
devmode-engine:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-devmode-engine-rust:1.1
    ports:
      - '5050:5050'
    container_name: sawtooth-devmode-engine-rust-default
    depends_on:
      - validator
    entrypoint: devmode-engine-rust --connect tcp://validator:5050
```

(From
https://github.com/danintel/sawtooth-cookiejar/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml )

Also, does the validator container run all the initialization commands (`sawadm`, `sawtooth keygen`, `sawset genesis`, `sawadm genesis`) before `sawtooth-validator` starts?